# How to add a checkbox column to Pandas data frame table in PyQt5

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt, pyqt5

I wrote some code to display a pandas data frame as a table in my Qt app. What I want to do is add checkbox column to this table. The user can then check mark some of the rows. They can then edit the values inside rows they check marked.

Basically I want my table to look like this:
[image: Basically I want my table to look like this:]

This is the code I have right now to populate the model with dataframe.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pandas as pd
class PandasModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel): 
    def __init__(self, df = pd.DataFrame(), parent=None): 
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        self._df = df

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            try:
                return self._df.columns.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QtCore.QVariant()
        elif orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            try:
                # return self.df.index.tolist()
                return self._df.index.tolist()[section]
            except (IndexError, ):
                return QtCore.QVariant()

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.QVariant()

        return QtCore.QVariant(str(self._df.ix[index.row(), index.column()]))

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        row = self._df.index[index.row()]
        col = self._df.columns[index.column()]
        if hasattr(value, 'toPyObject'):
            # PyQt4 gets a QVariant
            value = value.toPyObject()
        else:
            # PySide gets an unicode
            dtype = self._df[col].dtype
            if dtype != object:
                value = None if value == '' else dtype.type(value)
        self._df.set_value(row, col, value)
        return True



Model = PandasModel(data_frame)
self.apollo_table.setModel(Model)
```